# Question about the sentence »Jetzt erinnere ich mich wieder«

Tags: grammaticality

I have two questions about this:

1. Why is the verb "erinnere" before "ich mich wieder"? Can i say instead, "Jetzt ich erinnere mich wieder"?
2. What is the purpose of putting "mich" in the sentence? wouldn't that be saying I remember me(which doesn't seem to make sense)? Would it be correct if i eliminate the word "mich" from the sentence and just say, "Jetzt, erinnere ich wieder" ?

Thank you so much for taking time to answer my question, i truly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word order is much more flexible in German than in English, but there is one very hard rule:

- **In a declarative sentence** (i.e. not a question and not a command) **there MUST be a verb at grammatical position 2 of the sentence.**

(Note, that a grammatical position is for one part of speech, not for one word)

This are other correct versions of the same sentence:

> Jetzt erinnere ich mich wieder.
>   Ich erinnere mich jetzt wieder.
>   Wieder erinnere ich mich jetzt. (unusual, but still correct)

Also important for your question:

- The verb »erinnern« is a reflexive verb in German. This means: It always has to be used with a reflexive pronoun, which in case of »erinnern« has to be used in accusative case (*mich, dich, sich, uns, euch*). In Englisch *to remember* is not reflexive, so you must think different in German.

So, the purpose of »mich« in this sentence is just to make the sentence grammatically correct.

Comment: It might help the OP to think of it as "I remind myself", or at least to compare with that. English does have reflexive verbs, but they are not so obvious.

Comment: I am surprised that the OP did not ask why "wider" is necessary

Comment: @Mawg Well, may be it's because "**wider**" is not necessary ;)

Comment: Lol. Ok, then I am surprised why he did not ask why it was included

Answer (score 2):

1: The verb comes second: Jetzt (verb) ....

2: the verb is not "erinnern", but "sich erinnern". This is a reflexive verb. The difference between "erinnern" and "sich erinnern" is very subtile and difficult to explain in english. In some case (colloquial) you can only use "erinnern". In spanish there is also both variants, "recordar" and "recordarse". Literally translated "remember" and "remember myself"

may be a quick solution could be: sich erinnnern = remember, erinnern = remind